# Chrome max connections only allows 1 file to load at a time, how to increase?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, connection

on some sites in chrome, for example loading direct video files from a server only allows 1 current stream to play in browser until the next will load.

If i have a server with 2 direct video files, and i load both in separate tabs. File 1 will start to buffer/download and then file 2 will wait until file 1 has finished buffering/downloading.

How can i increase this limit and make both buffer/download at the same time?, as it makes chrome really slow right now.

Noet: This is not a server restriction because i can load file 2 in another browser so 2 current downloads but over 2 browsers. I would like chrome to load both file 1 and 2 at the same time and not have to wait for file 1 to complete.